# OSGeo4W64 to OSGeo4W (32bit) Environ setting issue

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo, osgeo4w, environment-variable

I normally use my Python script using OSGeo4W64 command shell on my 64-bit PC (Windows10). Now, I'm trying to use my script on a 32-bit machine (Windows10). In the 32-bit machine, there's an issue with importing the `from osgeo import osr` module.

I used the Advanced installer to install OsGeo4W shell. I installed all default modules except the 'setuptools' module (which is not installed by default and so I installed it).

In one of my Python files, I have the following (note the "`EnvSettings`" module I made):

```
import sys
import os
import math
import csv
import EnvSettings

from osgeo import osr
```

In `EnvSettings`, I have:

```
import os
path = os.environ['PATH']
pgdal= 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal;'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA']='C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal'
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH']='C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal\\gdalplugins'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB']='C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal\\projlib'
os.environ['PATH'] = "%s;%s" % (pgdal, path)
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ols_engine.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mdl
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\PyPack\v0.2_cells_op\mdl.py", line 8, in <module>
    import osr
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I also tried:

```
import os
path = os.environ['PATH']
pgdal= 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\share\\gdal;'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA']='C:\\OSGeo4W\\share\\gdal'
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH']='C:\\OSGeo4W\\share\\gdal\\gdalplugins'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB']='C:\\OSGeo4W\\share\\gdal\\projlib'
os.environ['PATH'] = "%s;%s" % (pgdal, path)
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ols_engine.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mdl
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\PyPack\v0.2_cells_op\mdl.py", line 8, in <module>
    import osr
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

When I just use Python from the shell, I tried:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\PyPack\v0.2_cells_op>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import osr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> from osgeo import osr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

And also:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import EnvSettings
>>> import osr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> from osgeo import osr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I struggle with understanding how to set environments. Can someone please provide some direction to make the `osgeo` and `osr` module work?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. 
The problem was when I installed OSGEO4W on this machine, I changed the local package directory.

[image: See below]

It was originally set to some other folder I can't remember what it was. But the problem was when I reset it to "c:\". Then I set it to "C:\OSGeo4W". This seemed to have fixed the problem.